# Justify content is not active over 768px

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand why my `justify-content: space-between;` is not working. As I see it then when the viewport hit `768px` the container should flex and have space between the 2 columns.

What am I missing here?

```css
.call-out-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    }
    .call-out {
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
    .call-out:nth-child(1) {background-color: pink}
    .call-out:nth-child(2) {background-color:blueviolet}

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .call-out-container {
            display:flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="call-out-container">
    <div class="call-out">
        <h4>Feature 2</h4>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="call-out">
        <h4>Feature 2</h4>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's taking full width because of the content inside the class call-out.
Try limiting the width of that class to see the result.

For example add this to your css:

```
.call-out{max-width: 300px}
```

justify-content is working just fine.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks. So it works when I set the `flex-basis:40%` instead.